# Is a partial target file created if an error occurs during AWS S3 copy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What happens to the target file (i.e. the file being written) if an error occurs *during* the copy-operation on AWS S3? The [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) states this;

> You create a copy of your object up to 5 GB in size in a single atomic action using this API

Does that mean that for files < 5 GB in size, no partial target file will be written/visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects will never be in a 'partial' in S3. Either the whole file is available, or none of it is.

If the file is less than 5GB, it can be uploaded with a normal `upload` command. If it works, then it appears. If it fails, then there is no change on S3.

Larger files need [Uploading and copying objects using multipart upload - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html). This uploads the file in 'parts', and each part can be retried. When all parts are uploaded, a final command tells S3 to join the parts into one Object.